# Access private attribute pathName of object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) - Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

This form upload receives a file, and I need its pathname to perform business logic on the file.

**in the Controller**

```
if ($uploadForm->isSubmitted() && $uploadForm->isValid()) {
           $targetDirectory = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../var/public';
           $filePath = $uploadForm['fichier_ine']->getData();
           var_dump($filePath);
        }
```

**In browser**
The dump returns:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'test.txt' (length=8)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
  private 'size' => int 1526
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phpDtf3r4' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phpDtf3r4' (length=9)
```

However I cannot access the private property pathName as it is private without getters.
Any help is appreciate since I am junior and beginner.

Comment: `$pn = (string) $filePath->pathName`

Comment: @MarkusZeller are you sure?

Comment: Pretty sure, because pathName contains a SplFileInfo object and if you call __toString() you will get its content value.

Comment: And `private` modificator not scares you?

Comment: I can't test it atm. So I commented and not answered.

Comment: When private properties will be accessible from outside - you will be able to post as answer.

Comment: Nice, I see dumped private properties above.

Comment: ->pathName didn't work but ->getPathname() did. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output gives you a hint, that `UploadedFile` extends [`SplFileInfo`](https://www.php.net/SplFileInfo). And the latter has `getPathname()` method, so:

```
var_dump($filePath->getPathname());
```

Comment: This worked. Seems I tried to use CamelCase as in: getPathName().

Comment: Method names are case-insensitive.